# How to nest a conversation with in another command telegram-bot-python

Tags: python, asynchronous, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ConversationHandler

TOKEN = "TOKEN"
BOT_USERNAME = "BOT"

# Use a set to keep track of registered users
registered_users = set()


async def start_command(update, context):
    user = update.message.from_user

    # Check if the user is already registered
    if user.id in registered_users:
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                                       text=f"Welcome back, {user.first_name}!")
    else:
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Let's make your account.")
        return await start(update, context)


async def error(update, context):
    print(f'Update {update} caused error {context.error}')


# States
FIRST, SECOND = range(2)


async def start(update, context) -> int:
    await update.message.reply_text("Hello! This is a conversation bot. What's your name?")
    return FIRST


async def get_name(update, context) -> int:
    user_name = update.message.text
    context.user_data['name'] = user_name
    await update.message.reply_text(f"Nice to meet you, {user_name}! What's your age?")
    return SECOND


async def get_age(update, context) -> int:
    user_age = update.message.text
    await update.message.reply_text(f"Thanks for sharing! Your age is {user_age}.")
    return ConversationHandler.END


async def cancel(update, context) -> int:
    await update.message.reply_text("Conversation canceled.")
    return ConversationHandler.END


conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
    states={
        FIRST: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, get_name)],
        SECOND: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, get_age)],
    },
    fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting Bot")
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()

    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    app.add_handler(conv_handler)
    app.add_error_handler(error)

    print("Polling...")
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=3)`
```

I want to start the conversation from my start_command after checking if user has registered already or not. The problem I am having is I am unable to figure out how to start the conv_handler and keep the states changing until the conversation is finished within the command start_command.

I looked at the documentation and could not find anything about nested conversation handlers inside other commands or functions. I am able to start on its own by giving its own command but I want to achieve this by making in initiate the start_command function.